# Dialog Popup not populating Angular Material ts

Tags: angular

So the problem that I am having is that I have created the format of the dialog popup for my current project, and most other answers to similar questions on this forum have answers that implement raw javascript into the code, something I do not wish to do. So in the stack order, first here is the confirmation component that is to be shared throughout the whole application:

Confirmation Component TS:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';

export class SharedConfirmationDialogObject {
    header: string;
    body: string;
    confirmBtnText: string;
    declineBtnText: string;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'acmx-shared-confirmation-dialog',
    templateUrl: 'confirmation.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['confirmation.component.css']
})
export class SharedConfirmationDialogComponent {

    constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<SharedConfirmationDialogComponent>,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: SharedConfirmationDialogObject) {
            console.log(data);
        }

    onNoClick(): void {
        this.dialogRef.close();
    }
}
```

Confirmation Component HTML:

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title><u>{{data.header}}</u></h1>
<mat-dialog-content>
    {{data.body}}
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-button type="button" mat-dialog-close>{{data.declineBtnText}}</button>
    <button mat-button type="button" (click)="dialogRef.close(true)">{{data.confirmBtnText}}</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

Affected Component TS Method

```
  public openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(SharedConfirmationDialogComponent, {
      width: '550px',
      height: '500px',
      data: {oilForm: this.oilForm}
      });
    }
```

Button that is to Initiate the popup:

```
<mat-card-actions class="text-center">
  <button mat-raised-button [disabled]="dataService.loading || dataService.oilForm.invalid" color="primary"
          (click)= "openDialog()">Submit
  </button>
```

This is where I begin to have problems because doing all of this, it brings me the outline of the popup, but any attempt I have made to populate the field with something, be it creating a new class html that handles the content within the dialog, creating local component objects that tie back to the shared dialog component and placing those in open dialog call (to which says upon browser inspection is an abstract control). I just simply need to know what it is that I need to do without the need to implement raw JS anywhere. Again, help and source citations on this matter are greatly appreciated.

Update: This is what I refer to when I say tying the shared component objects with local created dialog objects:

Same Affected TS:

```
private headerObject: SharedConfirmationDialogObject;
  private bodyObject: SharedConfirmationDialogObject;
  private confirmObject: SharedConfirmationDialogObject;
  private cancelObject: SharedConfirmationDialogObject;

  public setConfirmationObject() {
    this.headerObject.header = 'Oil Coupon Save Confirmation';
    this.bodyObject.body = 'Are You Sure You Want to Save? This Action Cannot Be Undone.';
    this.confirmObject.confirmBtnText = 'Save';
    this.cancelObject.declineBtnText = 'Cancel';
  }
```

Comment: This class `SharedConfirmationDialogObject` does not match `{oilForm: this.oilForm}`. So I'm confused as to what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Basically what I am trying to do is utilize the SharedConfirmationObject as it is something that is used throughout the whole application, and with that, oilForm is one of the forms and subsequent form groups that will use it. What is happening is that there is a method in which will add the pieces of the form and send them to the database. My problem is that the popup itself is not populating with anything, which I want to just have a save and cancel, the new save button in theory is the item that will initiate the call to persist the contents of the form to the database.

Comment: `@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA)` equals what you pass to `data: {oilForm: this.oilForm}`. This is the only way to pass data to a modal popup. The dialog template uses undefined properties of data. So it shows nothing.

Comment: Somehow, the SharedComponent Object is the item that is supposed to handle the format of the popup, and with that, is supposed to populate with the shared component html, to which it is not. Are you saying that is related to @Inject as well?